# best practice to update data from last 3 month in a very large Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables:

1. History Table A (10 billion records, non-clustered column stored index on all column, the table is partitioned pro every 6 months)
2. Staging Table B (2000 records, no partition)

I want to compare Table B with the data of last 3 months of Table A, and if the data from Table A is older, I will update them with the data from Table B.

My update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE COLUMN A=COLUMN B
FROM B 
JOIN A
WHERE DATE COLUMN B>DATE COLUMN A
```

The Problem is: this Query takes 5 hours to update only 2000 records. The JOIN between Table A and Table B takes too long time.

I have tried a lot to modify the query (e.g: add non-clustered index on Date column) but there is no better results

How can I improve the performance of this update query?

Comment: Have you reviewed the execution plan? I'm guessing you have bad indexes which is causing a 10billion row scan.

Comment: Hi dako,i have checked the execution plan. because the History Table A has non clustered column sotred index, the system scan all the INDEX instead of partition elimination, and it takes time. i don't really understand why the System does that

Comment: Add the index definition to your post.

Comment: can you post the actual update statement instead of pseudocode? Maybe you have functions in your where clause? Maybe you datatype mismatches on the joining columns? Without the actual table definitions (including indexes) and the actual update statement OR the execution plan nobody can do anything but guess.

Comment: Please do not post the same question independently to multiple forums - [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/862e8714-65e9-405a-9dcd-5846e64936a2/best-practice-to-update-data-from-last-3-month-in-a-very-large-table?forum=sqldatawarehousing)

Comment: If the table is partitioned as you described then I don't know how this could take much time at all, especially if the partition function runs over the indexed date column. Approximately how many records are contained in each 6 mos. partition, also is there an aligned index with the partition scheme?

Comment: Thanks Ross, in the last 6 th Partition , there is about 1 billion records. The Problem is that. i used the nonclustered column stored index not nonclustered index, therefore the system scan the whole nonclustered index, which takes a lot of time